# Uniform convergence and continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of functions. Is it possible that $(f_{n})$ converges uniformly where each functions (that is $f_{1},f_{2}, f_{3}\dots$) aren't necessarily continuous?

Comment: Do you mean that the limit is continuous?

Comment: No. I meant that $f_{1}, f_{2}, \dots$ aren't continous. I have edited my post. I am not sure if my question is absurd.

Comment: So are you just wondering whether the sequence could confirm uniformly at all?

Comment: Yes. I know well what it means to say that a sequence of functions converges uniformly but I do not know whether it requires that the functions $f_{1}, f_{2},\dots$ should be continous or not.

Comment: Well, for example, see André's answer.

Comment: Just for emphasis: Uniform convergence of $f_n$ assumes nothing more than tthat all $f_n$ are defined on a set, which may have no topology at all, hence where the notion of continuity is not even applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be **any** function at all, say your favourite discontinuous function. Let $f_n=f$ for all $n$. Then the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.

Somewhat less trivially, let $(g_n)$ be any uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions and let $f_n=f+g_n$. Then the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly, and the $f_n$ are not continuous if $f$ is not continuous.